# How to register a Windows global hotkey except for a specific program?

Tags: c#, vb.net

**Question**

I have created a "Foo" WPF application which shows its main window whenever the hotkey ctrl + shift + space bar is pressed anywhere in the Windows 10 OS. This works fine.

Now, a problem has occurred. With Visual Studio (2019), one of the shortcuts is also ctrl + shift + space bar (to show overload parameters when the cursor is between method parentheses). When pressing this hotkey when using VS, the "Foo" window shows up instead of the overload parameters list.

Therefore, I would like to make an exception in the "Foo" application for Visual Studio, so that when pressing this hotkey in Visual Studio, the overloads parameters shows up, and not the "Foo" application. What is the best way to achieve this? Is there a special RegisterHotkey parameter that can do this, or is it better to check if the active window is VS right before the "Foo" window shows up? Thanks.

**Code Snippet of current, working application**

```
Imports System.Windows.Interop
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Hotkey

Public Const WM_HOTKEY As Integer = &H312

Enum KeyModifier
    None = 0
    Alt = &H1
    Control = &H2
    Shift = &H4
    Winkey = &H8
End Enum

Public NotInheritable Class User32
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub
    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Friend Shared Function RegisterHotKey(hWnd As IntPtr, id As Integer, fsModifiers As ModifierKeys, vk As RecentWorkFolders.Keys.Keys) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Friend Shared Function UnregisterHotKey(hWnd As IntPtr, id As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function
End Class

<Flags>
Public Enum Modifiers
    NoMod = &H0
    Alt = &H1
    Ctrl = &H2
    Shift = &H4
    Win = &H8
End Enum

Public Sub InitializeHotkey()

    Dim windowHandle As IntPtr = New WindowInteropHelper(MainWindowInstance).Handle
    Dim result As Boolean = User32.RegisterHotKey(windowHandle, 1, ModifierKeys.Control Or ModifierKeys.Shift, RecentWorkFolders.Keys.Keys.Space)

End Sub

Public Sub HookWndProc(window As Visual)
    Dim source = TryCast(PresentationSource.FromVisual(window), HwndSource)
    If source Is Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine("Could not create hWnd source from window.")
    End If
    source.AddHook(AddressOf WndProc)

End Sub


Private Function WndProc(hwnd As IntPtr, msg As Integer, wParam As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr, ByRef handled As Boolean) As IntPtr

    If msg = &H312 Then
        handleHotKeyEvent(wParam)
    End If

    Return IntPtr.Zero
End Function


Public Sub handleHotKeyEvent(ByVal hotkeyID As IntPtr)
    Select Case hotkeyID
        Case 1
            IsWindowShown = False
            Initialize()
            ShowWindow()
    End Select
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Have you tried passing IntPtr.Zero for hwnd parameter of RegisterHotKey?

Comment: There is no such option.  Pretty universal issue with RegisterHotKey(), you are lucky to catch it early.  Very, very important to pick a key that isn't used by any other program.  One basic strategy is Ctrl+Alt+Function key, pick keys from the right because the ones on the left are often already used.  Intel shovelware is notorious.  To exclude by window you need another way to do it, setting a low-level keyboard hook and lots of pinvoke in the callback to identify the window in the foreground.  Do pick a better key.